# NullPointerException with CallableStatement.getResultSet()

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, t-sql, jdbc, jtds

I have a stored proc in SQL Server 2005, which looks like the following (simplified)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FOO
 @PARAMS
AS
BEGIN
  -- STEP 1: POPULATE tmp_table
  DECLARE @tmp_table TABLE (...)
  INSERT INTO @tmp_table
      SELECT * FROM BAR

  -- STEP 2: USE @tmp_table FOR FINAL SELECT
  SELECT abc, pqr
    FROM BAZ JOIN @tmp_table 
    ON some_criteria
END
```

When I run this proc from SQL Server Management Studio, things work fine. However, when I call the same proc from a Java program, using something like:

```
cs = connection.prepareCall("exec proc ?,");
cs.setParam(...);
rs = cs.getResultSet(); // BOOM - Null!

while(rs.next()) {...} // NPE!
```

I fail to understand why the first result set returned is NULL. Can someone explain this to me?

As a workaround, if I check cs.getMoreResults() and if true, try another getResultSet() - THIS time it returns the proper result set.

Any pointers please? (I'm using JTDS drivers, if it matters)

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Umm.  Did you call `cs.execute()` or `cs.executeQuery()` at some point?

Comment: Take a look at this answer here.
I explain clearly how the results are returned from database and how you should parse your result sets. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66455195/4884153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc for [`getResultSet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet()) says that it returns null "... if the result is an update count or there are no more results".  It looks like your stored procedure would have an update count *and* a resultset, and that the `getResultSet()` method is (arguably) just doing what the API contract says it should do.

You could try retrieving the update count first.  Otherwise, stick with your "workaround".

Comment: Yes. Also one thing I noticed is that "executeQuery()" seems to work all the time (never returns null).

Accepting your answer anyway...

Comment: @Raj - presumably if you execute using executeQuery there is no way to retrieve the update count.  (Question - is the update count from the INSERT actually retrievable?)

Answer (score 2):

Kind of pointless posting an answer after the correct answer has been selected I guess.

The solution I suggest is calling

```
set nocount on
```

before the insert statement and

```
set nocount off
```

afterwards. Inserts return a resultset otherwise.